# Flutter UI distorted

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Hi I am trying to Build and UI with

TITLE

IMG

Description

But because my title is 2 big mainly 2 lines i am getting `EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY` 
My Code is below:

```
Widget _buildRowItem() {
    final Row mainRow = new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(_feed.getTitle(),
            maxLines: 2, softWrap: true, textAlign: TextAlign.start),
      ],
    );
    final Container container = new Container(
      child: mainRow,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
      color: Colors.teal,
    );

    return container;
  }
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you i appreciate your response,

Between this solved my issue

```
Widget _buildRowItem() {
    final Column column = new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(_feed.getTitle(),
            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            softWrap: true,
            maxLines: 2,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
        new Container(height: 8.0),
        new Image.network(
          _feed.getImageUrl(),
          height: 164.0,
          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        )
      ],
    );
    final Container container =
        new Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), child: column);

    return new Card(child: container);
  }
```

UI:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Almost there  with your approach!

add a flexible wrapper and its done.

[image]

```
  Widget _buildRowItem() {
final Row mainRow = new Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    new Flexible(child: new Text('some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text ',
        maxLines: 2, softWrap: true, textAlign: TextAlign.start))

  ],
);
final Container container = new Container(
  child: mainRow,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
  color: Colors.teal,
);

return container;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use here Extended or Flexible with container specific hight

for example

 Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/3.5,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.5),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children:
                List.generate(mEmiMessagesList.length, (index) {
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Wrap(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            mEmiMessagesList[index].mValue,
                            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                })),
          ),
```